# Can anyone explain what this script does?

Tags: linux, bash

```
01 #!/bin/bash
02 HOSTFILE=myhosts
03 while read line
04 do
05 TMPLINE=$line
06 print $TMPLINE
07 done < $HOSTFILE
```

I cannot understand the use of the 7th line.

Comment: I/O redirection https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: That duplicate flag is not OK, the question is far more complex

Comment: Redirect stdin to the file myhosts. The loop "while ...do ...done" will have the file as input.

Comment: @Harry The question specifically asks about the 7th line of this script, so it seemed like a duplicate

Comment: @that other guy Yeah, remaining in silence forever